# Qt/C++ image does not appear on screen

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

Here is the code for the MainWindow constructor where I tried to make
 an image (000.jpg) appear on the screen. What could be wrong? Are there
 alternative ways of showing an image on screen from a file? PS: The
 image file is in the same directory where the .cpp project files are.

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow()
 {
     QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
     setCentralWidget(widget);

     QWidget *topFiller = new QWidget;
     topFiller->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

     QWidget *bottomFiller = new QWidget;
     bottomFiller->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

     QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
     layout->setMargin(5);
     layout->addWidget(topFiller);

     QImage myImg("000.jpg");
     myImageFile = myImg;
     imageLabel = new QLabel();
     imageLabel->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
     imageLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
     imageLabel->setScaledContents(true);
     imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImageFile));
     layout->addWidget(imageLabel);

     layout->addWidget(bottomFiller);
     widget->setLayout(layout);

     createActions();
     createMenus();

     setWindowTitle(tr("Image App"));
     setMinimumSize(160, 160);
     resize(480, 320);
 }
```

Comment: if you are going to use a relative path it must be relative to the executable, not the source code. Try placing the absolute path.

Comment: Is the image *definitely* being loaded successfully?  Check the return from [`myImg.isNull()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#isNull).

Comment: If you do not want to have these problems use qresource to store images. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem comes about because of ignore policy, the label *seems* failing to expand the layout (After or because *topFiller* and *bottomFiller* expand) :

```
  imageLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
```

try instead a normal policy by removing setSizePolicy(), or use *Expanding*:

```
imageLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

Also its good to set the QLabel setScaledContents so that the image will resize when you manually resize the view:

```
imageLabel->setScaledContents(true);
```